# sudo add-apt-key: command not found - Deepin 16.4

Tags: apt, package-management, deepin

I am trying to manually add keys as for some reason i an unable.

How could I be able to add a key manually without using `add-apt-key`

```
hutber@hutber-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.96.20.2-1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libnpth0:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
hutber@hutber-PC:~$ sudo add-apt-key 073E051D7B2AEE37
sudo: add-apt-key: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `apt-key add` - `apt-key` the command and `add` the subcommand/option (you might be confusing it with `add-apt-repository`). This is for adding a key from a file. If you want to fetch a key and add it, you need [`apt-key adv --recv-key`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-key.8.html):

```
adv
   Pass advanced options to gpg. With adv --recv-key you can e.g.
   download key from keyservers directly into the the trusted set of
   keys. Note that there are no checks performed, so it is easy to
   completely undermine the apt-secure(8) infrastructure if used
   without care.
```